# Loading image which waiting for AJAX request

Tags: jquery, ajax, loading

I have the following script which requests data through AJAX:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#input').keyup(function(){
            sendValue($(this).val());     
        }); 

    });
    function sendValue(str){
        $.post("ajax.php",{ sendValue: str },
        function(data){
            $('#display').html(data.returnValue);
        }, "json");

    }
```

I just want to show a DIV while the request is being made, and hide it when the data comes back. I've tried this:

```
$("#loading").ajaxStart(function(){
   $(this).show();
})
.ajaxStop(function(){
   $(this).hide();
});
```

But it didn't show or hide, it was always displayed.

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 1.10.1

Comment: You must attach `.ajaxStart()` to `document`, see my answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kxFDc/1/)**

As of **jQuery 1.8**, the `.ajaxStart()` method should only be attached to `document`. So:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function(){
    $("#loading").show();
})
.ajaxStop(function(){
    $("#loading").hide();
});
```

---

---

References:

- [`.ajaxStart()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) - jQuery API Documentation